# C #include and constants problem

Tags: c, include

I have these two files, functions.c and constants.h.

functions.c has this line:

```
#include "constants.h"
```

However, when I try to compile functions.c, functions.c functions can't find these constants from constants.c. These are const type constants. I know it's a very noobish problem, but I don't know the solution.

EDIT:
Files content (some of them):

functions.c:

```
#include <string.h>
#include "Directivas.h"
...
int hayDirectivaInclude(char* buffer) {
    if (strncmp(include, buffer, longInclude) == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

constants.h:

```
const char include[10] = { '#', 'i', 'n', 'c', 'l', 'u', 'd', 'e', ' ', 0 };
const int longInclude = 9;
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code how you define your code and where? Are the consts in constants.h or in constants.c?

Comment: @Markus They are in constants.h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `constants.h` must contain `extern` references to the constants.

For example, suppose you had: `const char* COOL_STRING = "Erandros is cool."` in constants.c. In order for `functions.c` to know about this string, you must inform it of its existence by writing `extern char* COOL_STRING;` somewhere, such as in `constants.h`

Comment: It didn't work. I separated extern's plus declarations in constants.h from declarations and initializations in constants.c

Comment: I take that back. I couldn't differentiate Eclipse's Code Analysis from the actual Compiler errors.

Comment: Incidentally, a useful feature of at least some C dialects is that extern array declarations may include initialization values.  The values themselves won't actually be used, but the number of values will be used to determine the array size.

Answer (score 0):

Are the constants declared in `constants.h`?  You should at least declare them there, or else the compiler won't know they exist when processing `functions.c`.

Answer (score 0):

see suppose you have declared some function in constants.h and its defination are in constants.c then when you are compiling function.c " just by including constants.h will not have include defination of those function . so it will give error...you need to compile both .c file wit together.